# Tailwind css when using React DaisyUI generating one css property wrong in production build only when done from Azure pipelines

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, daisyui

I have a react application that was setup using create react app. It also uses tailwind and React DaisyUI. I am having a strange issue with my CSS where if I build locally everything is fine. If I build then deploy to vercel it's fine. But when I build using our pipeline in Azure and deploy to our Kubernetes cluster, one bit of css is wrong. I am not even sure where to start since I can't reproduce outside of our Azure pipeline/deployment. Any direction on where to look would be helpful. The content property below should be "-" but instead it's rendering garbage characters. The character itself isn't anything special so I'm really at a loss.

Is there something explicit I should be doing in my build to insure this gets built correctly?

```
.collapse-open.collapse-plus>.collapse-title:after,.collapse-plus:focus:not(.collapse-close)>.collapse-title:after,.collapse-plus:not(.collapse-close)>input[type=checkbox]:checked~.collapse-title:after,.collapse-plus:not(.collapse-close)>input[type=radio]:checked~.collapse-title:after,.collapse[open].collapse-plus>.collapse-title:after 
    {
        content: "âˆ’"
    }
```

Comment: You can try specifying `@charset "utf-8";` at start of stylesheet.  More info you can check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@charset